# How to remove template parts inside a child theme, provided by a theme.json from it's parent theme in WordPress 5.9 FSE

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Since WordPress provides block themes and introduces theme.json api you can add template parts within a .json file from themes.

Parent theme (blocksbase automatic) `theme.json`

```js
{ 
   "templateParts": [
        {
            "name": "header-centered",
            "area": "header"
        },
        {
            "name": "header-default",
            "area": "header"
        },
        {
            "name": "header-linear",
            "area": "header"
        },
        {
            "name": "header-minimal",
            "area": "header"
        },
        {
            "name": "header-rounded-logo",
            "area": "header"
        },
        {
            "name": "header-wide",
            "area": "header"
        },
        {
            "name": "header",
            "area": "header"
        },
        {
            "name": "footer",
            "area": "footer"
        }
    ]
}
```

Once having a child theme.. you can just add more templateParts in the theme.json of the child theme. These will just be concatinated.

I tried the following:

My theme's `theme.json`

```js
{
    "templateParts": [
        {
            "name": "header",
            "area": "header"
        },
        {
            "name": "footer",
            "area": "footer"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hoping that it will only show 2 of them.. instead merging it with it's parent theme.json

I cannot find how i remove the theme parts from the parent theme within the child theme.

Within the previous hooks (actions and filters) with WordPress this was pretty straight forward however i cannot find any hooks on any interface or more dynamic way of manipulation of the theme.json(theme settings), for now it looks like a non-developer solution :(
but probably i am overseeing something.

Any insights are welcome!

Comment: Shouldn't this be in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/